# Is it possible to establish secure connection in android web view pre lollipop? if so how?

Tags: android, webview, certificate, insecure-connection, payfort

Hi am using PayFort payment gateway for transaction through android web view. Its working fine on lollipop. But pre lollipop it throws "**Could not establish secure connection**" as the patches for web view are not available on pre lollipop any more. Is there any way to establish secure connection on pre lollipop with android web view? if yes, do i have to use certificates for establishg secure connection? if so how can i achieve it(refer any link or tutorial)? Thank you.

```
webView.postUrl(serverUrl, EncodingUtils.getBytes(formattedRequestString, "base64"));
```

Comment: Hi, I 'm facing the same problem did you find any solution for this problem

Comment: I know its too late but it might help someone, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937701/1790537)